# How to initialize the Keystore

Tags: java, android, android-keystore, secret-key

This my code used for usage of key store to save an arbitrary text as a key in the keystore how I am getting the "Keystore is not initialized error", how can I initialise the Keystore?

```
public void secretKeyGeneration(View view) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    byte[]  sek = "eru9tyighw34ilty348934i34uiq34q34ri".getBytes();
    SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(sek, 0, sek.length, "AES");    
    char[] password = "keystorepassword".toCharArray();
    KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(sk);
    ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, protParam);

    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Keystores *have to* be initialized and hence you *have to* call the `Keystore.load(...)` method. In your case you can for instance invoke:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, null);
byte[]  sek = "eru9tyighw34ilty348934i34uiq34q34ri".getBytes();
...
```

Comment: I had tried ks.load(null) before and that had not worked, but your answer of ks.load(null, null) works great!

Comment: When is it initialized with the default cacerts? Thanks.